# Python random unicode string

Tags: python, unicode

I'm new to python and unicode. I'm trying to generate a random unicode string in python. This is what I came up with:

```
def randomUnicodeStr(self, ustart, uend):
    '''Generate a random unicode string whose length is strlen and whose unicode characters are in range ustart, uend'''
    strlen = 5
    uchars = [random.choice(range(ustart, uend+1)) for _ in range (strlen)]
    ustr   = u''
    for uc in uchars:
        ustr += unichr(uc)

    #for i in range(len(ustr)):
    #    print "Py char " + str(i) + " = " + str(ord(ustr[i]))

    return ustr
```

I'm not able to gather this information from python documentation, but what encoding does my `ustr` above use?.

Comment: Unicode strings aren't encoded, by definition. Encoding is what happens when you convert the string to bytes for writing to a device.

Comment: @MarkRansom: the RAM is a device too so it has to be encoded somehow. It believe it's UCS-4 in newest pythons, however, this fact is totally irrelevant for a python app developer.

Comment: A followup question - what exactly are you trying to do with the string, and why do you think you need to know the encoding? The code you put into the question looks perfectly adequate for your stated goal.

Comment: @MarkRansom: We have a setup where our regression tests are written in python and they call into our c++ code. This unicode string that I generate with this function, is used as an argument to a c++ function, which receives this string as an icu::UnicodeString. When I walk through the characters on the c++ side and print their code values, I see that they match the code values I set in my python function. Since I'm new to unicode, I was wondering whether I needed to be concerned about encoding since this string was crossing language boundaries. It doesn't appear to be, I'm okay I guess.

Comment: What you need then is the representation that is passed to the C API, which may be different than the internal representation (which is an implementation detail you shouldn't care about). See https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-393 for example.